# Error : C Program for Arithmetic Operations using Functions

Tags: c

I am trying to write a small c-program to perform arithmetic operations using functions, but facing some error.

Can some one please have a look on this code and verify it, please!

**Error:**

--------------------Configuration: mingw5 - CUI Debug, Builder Type: MinGW--------------------

```
Checking file dependency...
50: error: cannot convert `div_t' to `int' in assignment
64: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
69: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
74: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
79: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
84: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
90:2: warning: no newline at end of file

Complete Make Untitled25: 6 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

**CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
int mul(int, int);
int divs(int, int);
int print(int);

int main(){
int ans,a,b,n;

printf("******************");
printf("\n1 ADD");
printf("\n2 SUB");
printf("\n3 MUL");
printf("\n4 DIV");
printf("\n5 EXT");
printf("\n******************");
printf("\n\n\nEnter Your Option(1-5):");
scanf("%d",&n);

 // n=1;

printf("\nEnter Values a,b:");      
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

 // a=1;b=2; 

if(n==4&&b==0){
    printf("\n\n Value of `B` Can't Be `0` for Division\n\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


if(n>0&&n<6){



if(n==1){
    ans=add(a,b);
//  main();
}

if(n==2){
    ans=sub(a,b);
//  main();
}
if(n==3){
    ans=mul(a,b);
//  main();
}
if(n==4){
    ans=divs(a,b);
//  main();
}
if(n==5){
          exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}



print(ans);

}
else {
    printf("\nWorng Entry!\n ");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}



int add(int a,int b){
    ans=a+b;
        return(ans);
}

int sub(int a,int b){
    ans=a-b;
        return(ans);
}

int mul(int a,int b){
    ans=a*b;
        return(ans);
}

int divs(int a,int b){
    ans=a/b;
    return(ans);
}

int print(int ans){
    printf("\n\n Answer = %d",ans);
    return; 
}



}
```

I am using C-Free Professional to write and compile C Programs. I have tried on-line C-Program Compilers also. But same error.

Comment: Please don't continuously update the question as people solve your errors in the answers. Post a new question if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

This contains a function `div()` already which has a different return type to your `div` function hence giving this error.
To solve this you will either have to rename you `div` function or not use this include file.

For more info on the built in `div` see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_div.htm

Also you will need to take all of your functions and move them to outside `main`. Right now you have the following:

```
int main(){
...
int add(int a,int b){
    ans=a+b;
        return(ans);
}
...
}
```

which needs to be changed to

```
int add(int a,int b){
    return( a+b); //note there is no "ans" now
}

int main(){
...
...
}
```

Comment: Question Updated.. changed `div` to `divs`.. but still new errors :O

Comment: when i UPDATED like that it is showing `15: error: 'ans' was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 1):

`div()` is part of the standard library, and defined in `stdlib.h`, which you include in your program. You will have to use a different name for your function, for example `my_div`.

There are some more errors in your code - most important, standard C does not have nested functions.

Comment: thank you.. but i changed `div` to `divs`.. and still new errors :( question updated

Comment: @user3662340: Note the second paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

div already exists as a standard C function, and returns a different type. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725884/what-is-purpose-of-div-library-function)

You'll need to use a different name for your div.

Comment: thank you.. but i changed `div` to `divs`.. and still new errors :( question updated

Comment: div_t is the type returned by div, so you're using that somewhere. Are you sure you posted the exact code you're compiling?