# Using div with unsigned integers

Tags: c++, c, division

The C++ standard provides div(int, int), but not udiv(unsigned int, unsigned int).

If I naively used unsigned ints in this function, I can see that this would yield the wrong result for integers greater than 2^31 - 1 in the numerator. For example (with 4-bit nibbles):

The largest 4-bit nibble is 15, 1111 in binary. As a signed nibble, this would represent -1. Dividing 15 by 2 yields 7, or 0111, but dividing -1 by 2 yields 0: 0000.

Is there a straightforward way to adapt div to unsigned integers, or am I better off writing my own udiv, or avoiding the use of div and div-like functions altogether?

Edit/Note: In my case, I'm using `unsigned long long int`s, so using lldiv doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you use C++11? There's an overload for `long long`, which is at least 64 bits. And pick one language.

Comment: I'm actually using C++11 to divide a uint64_t. I should edit my question to indicate that I'm interested in adapting lldiv.

Comment: So, cast the `int` arguments to `long long`?

Comment: That doesn't work if the `unsigned long long` is greater than 2^63 - 1.

Comment: a detail here:  -1/2 is -.5  and when using an integer divide operation, fractions are always dropped.   So the result is the expected 0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Back in the day, the result of `/` and `%` were not uniquely defined by C and `div()` was born.  Now quotient from `/` is truncated towards 0.

`unsigned` math did not have this issue and so a lesser need for `udiv()`.

Now many compilers recognize nearby `a/b` and `a%b` calculations and optimize quite well, reducing the need for even `div()`.  Suggest just performing both calculations and let the compiler optimize it.

---

[Edit]
Detail: Prior to C99, division may truncate toward 0, toward `INT_MIN` or (maybe could round to nearest - I'll look into that).  In any case `%` is the remainder after the division.  `div()` was specified to only do one: divide with truncate toward 0.  With C99, both `div()` and `/` perform a division with the quotient truncated toward 0.

See
[What is purpose of the div() library function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725884/what-is-purpose-of-the-div-library-function)
[What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Comment: "integer division truncates fractional results toward 0."  Nothing else needs to be said

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an integer of n bytes, you can stocke k=2^n numbers, so if you have a negative number, getting its value as an unsigned would simply as adding k to it.

So what you could do is, test if the number is negatif, add k/q to the result.

However you could simply use the division operator /

Comment: That will work for other than 2s complement representation? And for 2s complement, what about `INT_MIN`, etc.?

Comment: this answer is not indicating why a integer divide where the divisor is greater than the numerator will always result in 0.