# Faster way of calculating array 2D position

Tags: c++

I have a custom image object, which is organised in tiles of fixed size, disposed in a tile grid. Let's assume, for instance, that the fixed `tileSize` is 256 pixels (each tile is a subimage of 256x256 pixels), and that my global image is 1000x500 pixels: this results in a tile grid of 4x2 tiles of 256x256 pixels.

Now, given a point in the global image coordinates, this is how I convert to tile coordinates (i.e., the tile position in the tile grid, plus the pixel position inside that pixel):

```
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
}

Point pGlobal = (...);

// Grid coordinates of the tile containing pGlobal
Point pTileGrid = Point(pGlobal.x / tileSize, pGlobal.y / tileSize);
// Pixel inside that tile that contains pGlobal
Point pTile     = Point(pGlobal.x % tileSize, pGlobal.y % tileSize);
```

The problem is that this is painfully slow. How can I optimize this?

Thank you in advance. If I did not explain myself correctly in any point please ask me to improve my formulation.

Comment: Why won't you post a minimal example so that people can jump into it in O(1) steps? :)

Comment: Are your tile sizes always a factor of two?

Comment: If this is slow for you, you are probably repeating this calculation in a tight loop. That would be wrong.

Comment: If `tileSize` is a power of 2, you should consider bit shifting and bit masking.

Comment: Please check [this SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661697/most-optimized-way-to-calculate-modulus-in-c) as it makes some good points regarding your problem.

Comment: If this is slow, your problem may be with your `Point` class - can you show us that?

Comment: To be clear - your Point class should be relatively trivial, and not perform any allocations. It should be coded such that you get good move / copy performance too.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes I am enforcing powers of two in tile size. can you guide me on some optimizations?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson thank you for pointing that out. `Point` is actually a simple struct, see the updated question :)

Comment: Use (struct div_t) [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div_t/] in order to get quotient and reminder in one call.

Comment: @sameerkn do you have any idea if that's faster or does it internally do the same?

Comment: @manatttta: Having gone through following answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565272/why-use-div-or-ldiv-in-c-c, result of `/` and `%` can be calculated in one call.

Comment: Depending upon number of times you do conversion from global co-ordinates to tile specific co-ordinates, you can with few MBs of extra memory can cache all the conversion results once.

Comment: A right shift will divide by a power of 2.  For example, "4 >> 1 == 2".  Usually shifting is a lot faster than a division.